# Removing rn_dev_preference XML file from React Native release APK decompiled source

Tags: xml, react-native, decompiler, release-apk

**Description**

we used the RN version 0.63.4 and somehow in the release build, we are getting rn_dev_preference XML in the build.

we need to remove the file for some security issues.
please suggest a way to remove the file from the release build.

The path on decompile build: res/XML/rn_dev_preference The path

React Native Version
0.63.4

Output of `npx react-native info`
[click to view info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cR10.png)

**Steps to reproduce**

create a build and just decompile the build you can see the file in res/xml/ folder

I'm using jadx apk-decompiler to decompile apk

**below file need to remove from decompiled relese apk version**

res/xml/rn_dev_preference.xml

To exclude the `rn_dev_preferences.xml` file from the release APK in React Native I tried below way by adding exclude path on release android block on `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
  // ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // ...
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'res/xml/rn_dev_preferences.xml'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But still there is `rn_dev_preferences.xml` present in release apk decompiled version and i'm expecting to remove it from `res/XML/` path